# Symmetric Expressions in Quadratic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

What is Symmetric Expression in Quadratic Equation?

As per the definition of my textbook, -

> The Symmetric Expressions of the roots $\alpha$, $\beta$ of an
>   equation are those expressions in $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which do not
>   change by interchanging a and b. To find the value of such expression,
>   we generally, express that in terms of $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha
> > \beta$.
>
> 1. $\alpha^2 + \beta^2$
> 2. $\alpha^2 + \alpha \beta + \beta^2$
> 3. $\frac 1 \alpha + \frac 1 \beta$

and this continues to some expressions.

So, I'm unable to understand -

**1. what are symmetric expressions in Quadratic Equations. (Can anyone explain by Diagram, then that'd surely help)**

**2. Why they are generally expressed in terms of $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha \beta$?**

**3. The given examples of the symmetric expressions (as given above 1, 2 and 3) aren't quadratic equations really, they seem to like in 2 variable. What are they? How are they derived? and What can be done  it?**

*Although I searched on Wiki and other websites on this topic, most of them were highly complicated beyond my level so, I can't seem to understand those*

Comment: $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha\beta$ are the *elementary symmetric functions* of $\alpha$ and $\beta$: the coefficients of $(x+\alpha)(x+\beta)$. The Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Functions implies that any symmetric polynomial in $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is a polynomial in the elementary symmetric functions.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown what is this -   elementary symmetric functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *1. what are symmetric expressions...*

As noted in the first paragraph, symmetric expressions are `those expressions in α and β which do not change by interchanging α and β`.

An expression in $\,a,b\,$ can be written as $\,f(a,b)\,$. Interchanging $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ gives the expression $\,f(b,a)\,$. By definition, the original expression is `symmetric in a and b` if and only if $\,f(a,b)=f(b,a)\,$ for all $\,a,b\,$.

- $\,f(a,b)=a^2+b^2+ab+1\,$ *is* symmetric in $\,a,b\,$ because $\,f(b,a)=b^2+a^2+ba+1$ $=a^2+b^2+ab+1=f(a,b)\,$ for all $\,a,b\,$.
- $\,f(a,b)=a^2-2b^2\,$ is *not* symmetric in $\,a,b\,$ because $\,f(b,a)=b^2-2a^2 \ne a^2-2b^2=f(a,b)\,$. Even though it *is* possible that $\,f(a,b)=f(b,a)\,$ for *some* $\,a,b\,$ e.g. $\,f(1,-1)=f(-1,1)\,$, the equality does not hold true for *all* values e.g. $\,f(1,0)=1 \ne -2 = f(0,1)\,$, so the expression is *not* symmetric.

> *...in Quadratic Equations.*

It's not about "*symmetric expressions* ***in*** *quadratic equations*", but rather "*symmetric expressions* ***in the roots of*** *quadratic equations*".

The first paragraph refers to `the roots α, β of an equation`. Since there are two roots, and assuming the context is *algebraic*, the equation must be a quadratic, such as $\,(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0\,$. Expanding and collecting, the quadratic can also be written as $\,x^2-px+q=0\,$, where $\,p=\alpha+\beta\,$ and $\,q=\alpha\beta\,$.

> *2. Why they are generally expressed in terms of $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha \beta$?*

- Because it is possible: by the [fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials), any polynomial expression in $\,\alpha,\beta\,$ which is *symmetric* in $\,\alpha,\beta\,$ can be expressed as a polynomial in the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Definition), which in the case of two variables are just $\,\alpha+\beta\,$ and $\,\alpha \beta\,$.
- Because it is convenient: by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Example), the elementary symmetric polynomials in the roots of a polynomial are directly related to the coefficients of the equation. In the simple case of a quadratic $\,x^2-px+q=0\,$, Vieta's formulas are precisely $\,\alpha+\beta=p\,$ and $\,\alpha\beta=q\,$ from the previous step.

> *3. The given examples of the symmetric expressions (as given above 1, 2 and 3) aren't quadratic equations really, they seem to like in 2 variable. What are they?*

Those are symmetric expressions in ***the roots of*** a quadratic equation.

Taking the first one for example, the complete statement of the problem would be something like:

$$
\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Find the value of the expression}} \;\alpha^2+\beta^2\; \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{where}} \;\alpha,\beta\; \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{are the roots of}} \;x^2 - px+q=0\,.
$$

Using the hint, and using that $\,\alpha+\beta=p\,$ and $\,\alpha \beta=q\,$, the expression can be calculated as:

$$
\alpha^2+\beta^2\color{red}{+2\alpha\beta-2\alpha\beta} = (\alpha+\beta)^2 - 2 \alpha\beta = p^2 - 2q
$$

It would be technically possible, of course, to actually *solve* the quadratic, find the roots $\,\alpha\,$ and $\,\beta\,$ explicitly, then calculate $\,\alpha^2+\beta^2\,$ the long and hard way. However, since the expression was symmetric, it was possible to calculate it a lot more quickly *without* having to actually find the individual values of $\,\alpha,\beta\,$.